# undefined output from body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

I'm trying to get the user input from the client side to the server side using body-parser in node.js. I am using express as a base of my application.

Here is the server side code:

```
app.post('/register', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
console.log("The text is: " + req.body.url)})
```

Here is the html form, from which I'm trying to extract the input:

```
 <form class="modal-dialog" action="/register" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="addModalLabel">Add comics</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                        Curently the amount of URL's supported is limited. Check out info page for more detailed
                        info.
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="url">URL of comics</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" aria-describedby="urlHelp"
                            placeholder="Enter URL">
                        <small id="urlHelp" class="form-text text-muted">For detailed guide on how to find URL go to
                            info
                            page.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
               
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The problem is that the output is undefined. I'm new to node.js so this might be an easy question, but I'm stuck for quite some time so please don't juge.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `name` attribute to your input: `<input name="url" … />`. Only form elements with a `name` attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

Within the form's `input` fields, the way node.js rexognizes these is by specifying the `name` field on the input on the front end. so like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" aria-describedby="urlHelp"
```

now on the backend since your route is a `.post` function, you can access it using `req.body.url`, which you are already doing!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share the way you've set up the server. First thing, `body-parser` is deprecated, you can use `express` to specify your middleware like so:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

`urlencoded` is the parser you need to parse HTML form data.